# How to sort file from document directory by Created Date in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsdate

I have a `NSMutableArray` that retrieved file from document directory in iOS.

i retrieved files from document directory with following codes.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSError * error;
    self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.array = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
```

And then i show the lists of file in `UITableView`.
However it show with Alphabetically.

I want to show it **sorted by Created Date of file.**

**Edit**

Here is i write in `ViewWillAppear`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSError * error;
    self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.array = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];

    [self loadData];  
 }

- (void) loadData
{
    self.sortedFileList = [self.array mutableCopy];
    [self.sortedFileList sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate* d1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:obj1 error:nil][@"fileCreationDate"];
        NSDate* d2 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:obj2 error:nil][@"fileCreationDate"];
        return [d1 compare:d2];
    }];

}
```

And It not sort by date.

How can i do that?

Thanks for any suggestions and help.

Comment: You don't provide the full context here, but I suspect you do this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Don't do that! You will re-sort your array for every cell you show.

Comment: Yes that below code is i wrote in cellForRowAtIndexPath. You mean i need to re-sort every single line from Array?

Comment: The code you show will be called once for every cell in your table. Which means that you will retrieve and sort the file list for every cell you show. And if that list differs for some reason between calls, you may end up with a crash (index out of bounds, etc).

Answer (score 3):

You need to us `NSFileManager` get the attributes (`attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`) for each file. This returns a dictionary for the file and you can get the creation date with `fileCreationDate`. Then you can perform your sorting.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is to store `FileNames` as a `Key` and `CreationDate` as a `Value` in some `NSDictionary` and then you can use ...

```
myArray = [myDict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
                  return [[obj2 date] compare:[obj1 date]];
          }];
```

Comment: What type would you store the creationDate in to require `[obj2 date]`? If it's `NSDate` then it would be `return [obj2 compare:obj1];` would it not?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the `sortUsingComparator:` method on the mutable array, e.g. (pseudo code):

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray* sortedFileList;
....

// Make sure to call this method *once* (i.e. from your VC when loading view).
- (void) loadData {
    self.sortedFileList = [self.array mutableCopy];
    [a sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate* d1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:obj1 error:nil][@"fileCreationDate"];
        NSDate* d2 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:obj2 error:nil][@"fileCreationDate"];
        return [d1 compare:d2];            
    }];

}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
    return self.sortedFileList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell* cell = // dequeue cell or create one



    cell.textLabel.text = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.sortedFileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
}
```

Comment: Better to use the `NSFileCreationDate` constant as the dictionary key.

Comment: Updated answer to clarify.

Comment: sorry bro. I write code like yours and doesn't sort correctly. :( BTW thanks you so much.

Comment: I dunno, remember that this was just pseudo code. I don't have the possibility ATM to run iOS code. Things to check for is that if you print the array out after it should be sorted, is it really sorted? Does the `attributesOfFileSystemForPath:obj2 error:nil][@"fileCreationDate"];` return something valid (I just based it off @Wain's answer)?

Comment: Why are you using `attributesOfFileSystemForPath` ?

Comment: Good spot! I meant of course the `attributesOfItemAtPath` method. I guess I copied the wrong line from the docs.